# Issue getting latest version of artifact from Nexus

Tags: nexus

I am trying to get latest snapshot version of an artifact from Nexus, and I just can't seem to make it work. The artifacts are uploaded as a zip (in case that affects) and are deployed in correct time-order (lower version before, higher version more recently). Based on couple of other SO answers here are some of the things I've tried.

The given artifact has a latest version of 0.8.400-SNAPSHOT, but all these searches give something else

Here is what I have for 0.8.400-SNAPSHOT

```
    <artifact-resolution>
        <data>
            <presentLocally>true</presentLocally>
            <groupId>x.y</groupId>
            <artifactId>artifactId</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.400-20160509.154907-1</version>
            <baseVersion>0.8.400-SNAPSHOT</baseVersion>
            <extension>zip</extension>
            <snapshot>true</snapshot>
            <snapshotBuildNumber>1</snapshotBuildNumber>
            <snapshotTimeStamp>1462808947000</snapshotTimeStamp>
            <sha1>61e08f995e9626ce67060af89798c37ff852d475</sha1>
            <repositoryPath>/x/y/artifactId/0.8.400-SNAPSHOT/artifactId-0.8.400-20160509.154907-1.zip
            </repositoryPath>
        </data>
    </artifact-resolution>
```

### Using Maven Resolve

1) /nexus/service/local/artifact/maven/resolve?r=snapshots&g=com.x.y&a=artifactId&e=zip&v=LATEST
returns 0.8.385-SNAPSHOT

```
    <artifact-resolution>
        <data>
            <presentLocally>true</presentLocally>
            <groupId>x.y</groupId>
            <artifactId>artifactId</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.385-20160506.162638-3</version>
            <baseVersion>0.8.385-SNAPSHOT</baseVersion>
            <extension>zip</extension>
            <snapshot>true</snapshot>
            <snapshotBuildNumber>3</snapshotBuildNumber>
            <snapshotTimeStamp>1462551998000</snapshotTimeStamp>
            <sha1>f70809137eb87a8dce98d7c4f746176a1305adfb</sha1>
            <repositoryPath>/com/x/y/artifactId/0.8.385-SNAPSHOT/artifactId-0.8.385-20160506.162638-3.zip
            </repositoryPath>
        </data>
    </artifact-resolution>
```

### Using Lucene Search

1) While a blanket search on all artifacts returns correct latest, it fails to give correct if I add any parameters to optimize it (by fetching less data). The query /nexus/service/local/lucene/search?r=snapshots&g=x.y&a=artifactId&e=zip returns all artifacts (count=14) with latestSnaphot as 0.8.400-SNAPSHOT:

```
    <artifact>
    <groupId>x.y</groupId>
    <artifactId>artifactId</artifactId>
    <version>0.8.385-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <latestSnapshot>0.8.400-SNAPSHOT</latestSnapshot>
    <latestSnapshotRepositoryId>snapshots</latestSnapshotRepositoryId>
    <repositoryId>snapshots</repositoryId>
    ...<snip>...
    </artifact>
```

2) A latest search does not return any data:
/nexus/service/local/lucene/search?r=snapshots&g=x.y&a=artifactId&e=zip&v=**LATEST**

3) A search to get one result shows wrong latestSnapshot:
/nexus/service/local/lucene/search?r=snapshots&g=x.y&a=artifactId&e=zip&count=**1** returns

```
    <latestSnapshot>0.6.265-SNAPSHOT</latestSnapshot>
```

4) A search with a higher count shows different version, but still with 0.6.265 as latest, until I hit almost entire the count of artifacts
With 10 as count /nexus/service/local/lucene/search?r=snapshots&g=x.y&a=artifactId&e=zip&count=**10**

```
    <version>0.6.261-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <latestSnapshot>0.6.265-SNAPSHOT</latestSnapshot>
```

With 12 as count, /nexus/service/local/lucene/search?r=snapshots&g=x.y&a=artifactId&e=zip&count=**12**

```
    <version>0.6.265-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <latestSnapshot>0.8.400-SNAPSHOT</latestSnapshot>
```

Is there a bug, or am I doing something wrong here?